# Submit form after onbeforeunload event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to submit a form after a `onbeforeunload` event in JavaScript and it does not seem to entirely work well. Or maybe it could be that I am not doing it well in code.

In my JavaScript, this is the code I have:

```
function setPopUpWindow(submitForm){
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (submitForm == false ) {
        return "Unsaved Data would be lost";
        document.getElementById("popUpForm").submit();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The user sees an alert box after they try and close the browser. After they click on OK in the alert box I am hoping the form would be submitted.

There is a reason why I want to submit the form after they click on close button. I want to get an exit status which I would use for something else in my code (I have an idea of how I am going to implement it).

Comment: It doesn't work this way, I'm afraid. See, when the parser hits `return` statement in a function, it does exactly that - stops the function' execution. So no form submit will be made.

Comment: I suppose what you intend to do should be implemented in `onunload` handler instead, as this event will be fired right after user hits 'Ok' on your `onbeforeunload` message.

Comment: Sad face, thanks for your input. I will use the `onunload` event that you suggested and see how well it works. Thanks again!

Comment: The form is sent via AJAX, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do some ugly stuff in order to achieve what you want:

```
var saveBeforeUnload = false;
setInterval(function() {
  if (saveBeforeUnload) {
    saveBeforeUnload = false;
    document.getElementById("popUpForm").submit();  
  }
}, 500);

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (submitForm == false) {
    saveBeforeUnload = true;
    return "Don't you want to save before leaving this page?";
  }
};
```